# Adding revision information

Tags: java, sbt

I want to add Git revision information to Java application built with SBT. Currently I'm using code generation feature as described here http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html to generate a class with `revision` field. A servlet class reads this field and renders HTML page with revision information. Everything works fine except the fact that generated file is transient and IDE (Intellij IDEA in this case) reports errors in servlet class. Obviously, I could generate the whole servlet class but that seems a bit too much to put in a build definition. Is there a way to make this file "permament" or am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Could you be hitting this issue: [sbt/issues/1664](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1664)?

If you can use generated scala, [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) is worth a look. You could add the git revision like so:

```scala
import sbtbuildinfo.{ BuildInfoKey, BuildInfoPlugin }
import sbtbuildinfo.BuildInfoKeys._

myProject
  .enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin)
  .settings(
    buildInfoKeys ++= Seq[BuildInfoKey](
      BuildInfoKey.action("revision") {
        Try(
          Process("git rev-parse --short HEAD").!!.trim
        ).getOrElse("unknown")
      })
    }
```

Comment: love it! You may want to put it in a `Try` incase git is not installed on the computer. `Try(Process("git rev-parse --short HEAD").!!.trim).getOrElse("unknown")`

Comment: cap doffed @Stephen!